# Unable to import java class from a non android java project to android project

Tags: java, android, import, sms, udp

Im creating a SMS communication app between my phone and my computer.

I have an issue concerning the objectclass that im suppose transfer over an UDP socket.

My object is called Message and it implements serializable.

I have a Java Project with a Server application and a Android Project with a Client application. My problem is that I cant implement the Message.java into the android project from the java project nor the other way, I have to make a copy of that class in both projects. I then get this error:
*Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: AndroidApp.Message*

This is my android application:

```
    @Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent){
    Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();        
    SmsMessage[] msgs = null;         
    if (bundle != null){
        Object[] pdus = (Object[]) bundle.get("pdus");
        msgs = new SmsMessage[pdus.length];         

        for (int i=0; i<msgs.length; i++){
            msgs[i] = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[])pdus[i]); 
            Message message = new Message(msgs[i].getOriginatingAddress(), msgs[i].getMessageBody().toString());
            try {
                sendMessageToServer(message);
            }catch(Exception e);


    private void sendMessageToServer(Message m) throws IOException {

    ByteArrayOutputStream bStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    ObjectOutput oo = new ObjectOutputStream(bStream); 
    oo.writeObject(m);
    oo.close();

    byte[] serializedMessage = bStream.toByteArray();

    InetAddress IPAddress = InetAddress.getByName("10.0.2.2");
    DatagramSocket clientSocket = new DatagramSocket();

    DatagramPacket sendPacket = new DatagramPacket(serializedMessage, serializedMessage.length, IPAddress, 8080);

    clientSocket.send(sendPacket);
    clientSocket.close();
}
```

My Message class is just simply Message(String phoneNum, String msg).

My Server looks like this:

```
public class Server {  
public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception{

    DatagramSocket serverSocket = new DatagramSocket(8080);
    byte[] receiveData = new byte[100000];

    while(true){
        DatagramPacket receivePacket = new DatagramPacket(receiveData, receiveData.length);
        serverSocket.receive(receivePacket);
        ObjectInputStream iStream = new ObjectInputStream(new ByteArrayInputStream(receivePacket.getData()));
        Message message = (Message) iStream.readObject();
        iStream.close();
        System.out.println("RECEIVED FROM: " + message.getPhone() + ": " + message.getMessage());
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure the packages are visible? named correctly?

Comment: How do I know if the packages are visible or not? all my clases are public so far.

Comment: Sorry. To be more precise: If the class is in another package, have you `import`ed that package?

Comment: Im not able to import the package

Comment: I figured it out. I just had to add the project to build path. I also had to go Project > Clean...